# How to increase non-numeric column value?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column that is used for a sequence number.
The values in the column look like 'WT0000004568'

I need to find the maximum value and increment the counter part by 1 to create a new sequence number.
For this example, the resultant value would be 'WT0000004569'.

How do I do that?

Comment: Be careful about concurrency issues when looking up the old value and incrementing by one. Do you have a unique index on the column? Also consider using an Oracle sequence to produce these values.

Comment: Oracle SQL allows you to write user-defined functions in Java, but I think what you want can be done in pure SQL.  A little clarification however, on top of what Thilo asked above:  Is it proposed to assign a new sequence "number" only when a new row is inserted?

Comment: I realize there are concurrency issues, but I'm not worried about that at this time.  This is an existing database, and I cannot change the design, so the Oracle sequence is not an option.  I was able to get things working to a point, but I ran into a problem.

Comment: I can get a prefix and a numeric value of '0000004569' like I want, but when I attempt to concatenate them by using either the concat() function, or the '||' expression, I get a space between the prefix and number, like 'WT 0000004569'.  Why is that?

Answer (score 5):

As Thilio pointed out, this is generally a bad design both from a performance and from a concurrency issue.  If we assume that you have a single user system and aren't particularly concerned about performance, you could do something like

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select 'WT' ||
  2         to_char(
  3           to_number(substr('WT0000004568',3)) + 1,
  4           'fm0000000000')
  5*   from dual
SQL> /

'WT'||TO_CHAR
-------------
WT0000004569
```

Comment: To clarify a question asked in a comment and addressed by Justin's answer: the original poster was seeing a space when he concatenated a string and a number because the implicit number-to-string conversion mask adds a space to the front of positive numbers to make them align well with negative numbers. To suppress this, you need to explicitly convert the number to a string, using "fm" at the beginning of the format string.